# Force git to use specific key when pushing

Tags: git, ssh

When I'm pushing to a Git repository from a Groovy script, Git is using a HTTPS connection with username and password, instead of an SSH key, as I would want.

I would like to force Git to use a specific SSH key when pushing to a remote, something like this:

```
git --sshKey='ssh://git@my-repo.com/my-project.git' push
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 2):

#### Create a SSH config file

> When you have multiple identity files, create a SSH config file mechanisms to create aliases for your various identities.
>
> You can construct a SSH config file using many parameters and different approaches.
>
> The format for the alias entries use in this example is:
>
> ```
> Host alias 
>   HostName AAAA.org 
>   IdentityFile ~/.ssh/identity
> ```
>
> To create a config file for two identities (workid and personalid), you would do the following:

```
Open a terminal window.
Edit the ~/.ssh/config file.
```

If you don't have a config file, create one.
Add an alias for each identity combination for example:

```
Host workid
HostName AAAA.org
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/workid

Host personalid
HostName BBBB.org
IdentityFile ~/.ssh/personalid
```

Comment: And after I create this, what should I do? `git --sshKey='workid' push`?

Comment: You will need to do anything. the key will be chosen automatically you simply type `git push`

Comment: OK, so at the moment I have a key in `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`. Why is that one not chosen automatically?

Comment: If you will use the configuration file as i described above you have to define each key per server

Comment: So `workid` and `personalid` are server IDs? And each key is dedicated to one server?

Comment: You're missing a step here @CodeWizard.  You need to show how to use the host from the command line: `git push workid:my-project.git`

Comment: You can but you don't must to do so , the config file will "handle it" when it will match the url of the server. you need to mention it if you are using the same key for the 2